# IF ELSE check variable value without needing to define entire resultset

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two similar queries I use for work research and I am trying to use a boolean variable to decide which one is run.

**The problem:**

In order to save a variable, I think I need to use a PL/SQL block, which seems to require me to define every column of my resultset and bulk collect into the resultset. I am setting this up as a template for my coworkers, most of whom know only very basic SQL, so I can't ask them to define new columns.

Is there some way for me to allow them to set the boolean variable and run the corresponding SQL query outside of the PL/SQL block? Is there some better way to do it?

**What I Have So Far (Doesn't Work):**

```
Declare Submit_Denied_Lines Boolean;
Begin Submit_Denied_Lines := True; --or false depending on their needs

If Submit_Denied_Lines = False Then
    GOTO Qry_Status_X;
Else
    GOTO Qry_Resolution;
END IF;
END;

<<Qry_Status_X>>

(The Status_X query)

GOTO The_End;

<<Qry_Resolution>>

(The Resolution query)

<<The_End>>
```

**Notes:**

If what I am asking is not possible, I will post two SQL files for them to use and leave notes about which one applies to which situation.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are you doing with the query?  Potentially, you want a stored function that takes a boolean parameter and returns a `sys_refcursor`.  Your SQL*Plus script would then declare a local `sys_refcursor` variable which SQL*Plus knows how to `print`

Comment: Thanks, I'm already glad I asked because now I can read up on `sys_refcursor`s. I am not sure this is the answer to your "what are you doing with the query" question, but each of the two queries pulls 16+ columns of claims data for the claim numbers my coworkers input. If Submit_Denied_Lines = False, then one of the columns will be Status_X and the query will have some additional code to get only the claims' latest Status_X. If not, one of the columns will be resolution, which always only shows the current state.

Comment: Is this a `SQL*Plus` script that your colleagues execute that runs a query and prints the results to the screen?  Spools the data to a file?  Writes the data to another table?  That's what I'm asking when I ask about what you're doing with the data.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! The query prints the results to the screen and then the program (Benthic's Golden) exports the data to Excel.

Comment: So it is not a SQL*Plus script?  This is something that "Benthic's Golden" runs?  Or are you saying that you have a SQL*Plus script that writes data to the screen and then Benthic's Golden imports the data from, what, a screen scrape?

Comment: Any chance we could continue [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82130/sql-help-justin-cave)? My lack of knowledge is holding you up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82133/discussion-between-puzzlepiece87-and-justin-cave).

Comment: @Justin Cave I can read up on sys_refcursor myself, but if you want to post an answer about it I will accept it as long as someone else would be able to follow along if they had the same question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a lot of information.  Is it the same select but with different criteria? (where clause) or completely different

This is one method of doing it if its completely different.  **This is runnable**

```
declare
    submit_denied_lines   boolean := true;
begin
    if submit_denied_lines then
        for i in (select 'Status_X' as t from dual) loop
            dbms_output.put_line (i.t);
        end loop;
    else
        for i in (select 'Qry_Resolution' as t from dual) loop
            dbms_output.put_line (i.t);
        end loop;
    end if;
end;
```

Here is one if the select clause is the same but the where clause is different **This is runnable**

```
declare
    submit_denied_lines   boolean := true;
    test                  char (1);
begin
    /* can't use boolean in the SQL engine */
    if (submit_denied_lines) then
        test := '1';
    else
        test := '0';
    end if;

    for i
        in (select *
              from user_objects
             where (user_objects.object_type = 'TABLE' and test = '1') or (user_objects.object_type = 'VIEW' and test = '0')) loop
        dbms_output.put_line (i.object_name);
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the upsides of using this over refcursor are that you do not have to use a stored procedure but that the downsides are that dbms_output may need to be set to on and assigned a size before it can be used?

Comment: I prefer using implicit cursors over explicit.  Are you doing this in a pl/sql block?